# Method for any class derived from a generic base class

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

Is it possible to have one `PrintList()` method cover `Kid`, `Student` and `Person` classes?

I don't want to implement `PrintList()` as a class method into `Person` or `Kid`, `Student` and `Person`.

```
public class Person<T>
{
  public T Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Kid : Person<byte> { }
public class Student : Person<short> { }
public class Adult : Person<int> { }
/* ... more classes ... */


class Program
{
  static void PrintList(List<T> list) where T : Person  /* NOT POSSIBLE */
  {
    foreach (var item in list)
      Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, Name: {1}", item.Id, item.Name);
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var students = new List<Student>();
    students.Add(new Student() { Id = 1, Name = "SA" });
    students.Add(new Student() { Id = 2, Name = "SB" });

    var adults = new List<Adult>();
    adults.Add(new Adult() { Id = 1, Name = "AA" });
    adults.Add(new Adult() { Id = 2, Name = "AB" });
    adults.Add(new Adult() { Id = 3, Name = "AC" });

    PrintList(students);
    PrintList(adults);

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all you need to make the `PrintList` method generic by adding a type parameter:

```
static void PrintList<T>(List<T> list) where T : Person /* still doesn't work */
```

But this still doesn't work, because `Person` isn't a type; only `Person<T>` is for some `T`. We actually need two type arguments:

```
static void PrintList<T, U>(List<T> list) where T : Person<U>
```

This works in the definition, but it means that you have to explicitly supply the types  when you call the method:

```
PrintList<Student, short>(students);
PrintList<Adult, int>(adults);
```

This is workable, but ugly. Can we do better?

Turns out we can. IF you make your signature

```
static void PrintList<T>(IEnumerable<Person<T>> list)
```

then you can go back to not supplying any type argument. You lose the ability to treat `list` like a `List` inside the method, but you weren't using that anyway.